# Service worker error on a Jekyll GitHub pages site

Tags: jekyll, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a Jekyll on GitHub pages site. For PWA functionality, I have a `service-worker.js`.

With the site live, opening Dev Tools on Chrome, I have the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'Cache': Request method 'POST' is unsupported
```

As you may see on the following code snippet of my `service-worker.js` the error is reported at `.then( cache => cache.put(request, copy) );`.

What shall I do to overcome this error?

```
// Try and serve up cached page, or else show networked page, or else show offline page

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  let request = event.request;

  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(request)
      .then(response => {
      return response || fetch(request)
        .then( response => {
          // NETWORK
          if (response && response.ok) {
            let copy = response.clone();
            caches.open(offlineCache)
              .then( cache => cache.put(request, copy) );
          }
            return response;
        })
      .catch( error => {
        // OFFLINE
        if (request.mode == 'navigate') {
          return caches.match(offlinePage);
        } 
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`POST` requests can't be used as keys in the Cache Storage API.

While you might sometimes want your service worker to respond to `POST` requests (if you, for instance, are using the [background sync API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Synchronization_API) along with IndexedDB to save and replay failed `POST` requests), most of the time you'll just want to exempt non-`GET` requests from your service worker's `fetch` response logic.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.method !== 'GET') {
    // By returning without calling event.respondWith(),
    // the default network behavior will be used, as if
    // there is no service worker involvement.
    return;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    // The rest of your existing logic can go here.
  );
});
```